# Resolving a sum after making a substitution

Tags: replacement, summation, algebraic-manipulation

Consider the following sum as expressed by $s3$:

```
l[i_, j_, 
  n_, λ_] := (a[λ]^Mod[j - Mod[i + 1, n, 1], n] + 
   a[λ]^(n - Mod[j - Mod[i + 1, n, 1], n]) + 
   a[λ]^Mod[j - Mod[i - 1, n, 1], n] + 
   a[λ]^(n - Mod[j - Mod[i - 1, n, 1], n]))

s[i_, n_, λ_] := 
 Sum[l[Mod[i + 1, n, 1], j, n, λ]*e[c[j]], {j, 1, n}] + 
  Sum[l[Mod[i - 1, n, 1], j, n, λ]*e[c[j]], {j, 1, n}] + 
  Sum[l[Mod[i + 1, n, 1], j, n, λ]*e[z[j]], {j, 1, n}] + 
  Sum[l[i, j, n, λ]*e[z[j]], {j, 1, n}]

s2[i_, n_, λ_] := 
 Evaluate@(s[i, n, λ] //. 
    Sum[x_*y_, {v_, vmin_, vmax_}] + Sum[z_*y_, {v_, vmin_, vmax_}] :>
      Sum[y*(x + z), {v, vmin, vmax}])

rule = e[c[j_]] :> Boole[j == 3] c[3] + Boole[j != 3] c ;
s3[i_, n_, λ_] := s2[i, n, λ] /. rule
```

I'm trying to resolve a part of this sum (the part that involves $c$):

```
FullSimplify[s3[1, n, λ], 
 n ∈ Integers && n > 3 && a[λ] ∈ Reals && 
  0 < a[λ] < 1]
```

I was expecting to get a result since:

```
FullSimplify[Sum[l[1, j, n, λ], {j, 1, n}]*c, 
 n ∈ Integers && n > 3 && a[λ] ∈ Reals && 
  0 < a[λ] < 1]
```

delivers the expected result

```
(*(2*c*(a[λ] + 1)*(a[λ]^n - 1))/(a[λ] - 1)*)
```

How can I sort this out? I couldn't do even a simpler version of the problem:

```
FullSimplify[s2[1, n, λ] /. e[c[j]] -> c, 
 c ∈ Reals && n ∈ Integers && n > 3 && 
  a[λ] ∈ Reals && 0 < a[λ] < 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

l[i_, j_, n_, λ_] :=
 a[λ]^Mod[j - Mod[i + 1, n, 1], n] +
  a[λ]^(n - Mod[j - Mod[i + 1, n, 1], n]) +
  a[λ]^Mod[j - Mod[i - 1, n, 1], n] +
  a[λ]^(n - Mod[j - Mod[i - 1, n, 1], n])
```

I have changed [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) to `Inactive[Sum]` to limit the number of attempts to symbolically evaluate the sums. Just use [`Activate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html) to revert to `Sum`

```
s[i_, n_, λ_] :=
 Inactive[Sum][l[Mod[i + 1, n, 1], j, n, λ]*e[c[j]], {j, 1, n}] +
  Inactive[Sum][l[Mod[i - 1, n, 1], j, n, λ]*e[c[j]], {j, 1, n}] +
  Inactive[Sum][l[Mod[i + 1, n, 1], j, n, λ]*e[z[j]], {j, 1, n}] +
  Inactive[Sum][l[i, j, n, λ]*e[z[j]], {j, 1, n}]
```

The rule for combining sums is modified to work with `Inactive[Sum]` as well

```
rule1 = {
   Sum[(x_)*(y_), {v_, vmin_, vmax_}] + 
     Sum[(y_)*(z_), {v_, vmin_, vmax_}] :> 
       Sum[y*(x + z), {v, vmin, vmax}], 
     Inactive[Sum][(x_)*(y_), {v_, vmin_, vmax_}] + 
         Inactive[Sum][(y_)*(z_), {v_, vmin_, vmax_}] :> 
       Inactive[Sum][y*(x + z), {v, vmin, vmax}]};

s2[i_, n_, λ_] := Evaluate[s[i, n, λ] //. rule1]

rule2 = e[c[j_]] :> Boole[j == 3] c[3] + Boole[j != 3] c;

s3[i_, n_, λ_] := Evaluate[s2[i, n, λ] /. rule2]

Assuming[
 n ∈ Integers && n > 3 && a[λ] ∈ Reals && 
  0 < a[λ] < 1, 
 s3[1, n, λ] //
    FullSimplify // Activate // Simplify]
```

[image]

You are using `c` as both a variable and as an indexed variable (or  a function). This could cause some confusion.